# Help getting URL linked to by Reddit post With PRAW

Tags: python, api, reddit

Using Praw I am trying to get the post linked to in the title of a Reddit submission. For example the [submission](http://www.reddit.com/r/AdviceAnimals/comments/1adu71/apparently_people_still_need_to_hear_this/) links to this [image](http://i.qkme.me/3te2bn.jpg). I have tried figuring out a way to extract this information from the **Submission** object in **PRAW** however even when browsing the source I have not been able to find this information. This seems like something that should be easy so I may be missing something.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import praw

user_agent = praw.Reddit("my_cool_user_agent")
link = "http://www.reddit.com/r/AdviceAnimals/comments/" + \
        "1adu71/apparently_people_still_need_to_hear_this/"
submission = user_agent.get_submission(link)
print submission.url
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import praw  

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Test Script')
submissions = r.get_subreddit('wtf').get_top(limit=10) 
for item in submissions:
    print item.url
```

Comment: This is the same answer as John has already given - i.e. use the url property - with a different way to get the post.  SO is not a database of code snippets, so please don't do that.  Instead look for ways that you can improve on existing answers

Comment: I disagree.  These are different answers.  The answer that John gave did not help me with a similar problem, but the answer by Gijs Joost Brouwer did help me.