# Error when using Reddit and Tumblr API to receive a reddit url and post it as a tumblr image

Tags: python, tumblr, reddit, praw, pytumblr

I am writing a script that takes some posts from a specified subreddit and then using that url to create an image post on tumblr usin both sites api's and python. My issue is that when i attempt to retrieve the url from reddit to post to tumblr my program instead prints the url of a random subreddit (always the url https://www.reddit.com/r/accidentallyliberian/) i was wondering what the error is in my code and why it is printing that url rather than one that i specified in my if statement regarding strings containing'.img' or '.png' in the url.

```
import praw
import json
import pytumblr

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     user_agent='url grabber by /u/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     username='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

oauth_token = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token'
AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize'
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token'
consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
)

#print(reddit.user.me())
def get_post_url(subreddit, amount):
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).hot(limit = amount):
        if '.img' or '.png' in submission.url:
            client.create_photo('username', state="published", tags=["testing", "ok"],
                                source = submission.url)
            #urllib.request.urlretrieve(submission.url, filename)

            print(submission.url)
        else:
            print('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_post_url('funny', 1)
```

Comment: Hi, if it's printing a random subreddit url how can it always be /r/accidentallyliberian. Either it's random or it isn't? Also noticed, `if '.img' or '.png' in submission.url:` won't work, you need if .img in submisison.url or .png in submission.url

Comment: Thanks for the advice, so i fixed that issue with the "or" but now I believe that the urls i'm requesting are of the post itself which wouldn't end in a .jpg. or .png which is stopping me from parsing those urls and then posting the image to tumblr. So i guess my question now is how would i use praw to get the image url and not the post's url?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445199/help-getting-url-linked-to-by-reddit-post-with-praw

Comment: Thank you very much that should get me going in the right direction.